# DNA extraction methods for hair?

Tags: dna, pcr, hair, dna-isolation

**TLDR: Can anyone state a extraction and isolation method(s) for genomic DNA for hair that will be used for PCR, in detail is preferable since I am a novice.**

I tried googling for DNA extraction methods for hair(follicles and/or root) and found various sources, the one that had the most detail involved the use or organic compounds we do not have access to. Is their preferred method of extracting DNA from hair, given that the genomic DNA would be in low amounts, I figure that might have something to do with the extraction process.

Comment: Can you please give us some background? It would make answering the question easier.

Comment: http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0069588

Comment: @Chris          That was pretty much all the background there is, I am a undergrad novice who needs to extract DNA from hair for a proffesor's research. He sent me on this task as a way of self learning i believe, but I guess I am not "up to snuff", given my asking here.

Comment: @MattDMo        I saw that source, but i lack the powder(s) to do it.

Comment: @RoSiv When you write that you have no access to certain organic compounds without specifying what you can do, it is hard to give recommendations.

Comment: @Chris          This speaks to my ineptitude i suppose, I have no access to the phenol or chloroform and cant do the organic extraction method. I do not really want to either, given i have never worked with it before. I was hoping there would be a "simple" solution with alot of "common" lab ingredients.

Comment: I'm sorry, you don't have access to *laundry powder*? I find that very difficult to believe.

Comment: @RoSiv These are important informations that belong into your question. I am used to  work with hazardous chemicals (with the right protective equipment) as  this is part of my training. Nothing special about it.

Comment: @Chris               If I were to do the organic, phenol/chloroform extraction, would you have any advice or suggestions, sources/methods even?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been trying to figure out something that works for some time.  I have recently tried 3 cheap protocols using commonly available lab reagents.  I was using buccal samples (0.2 ml of spit).

1) Boil the sample in Tris EDTA Buffer
2) NaOH Extraction
3) Direct N Lyse

I compared them to a genomic DNA extraction kit (FAST DNA Prep - MP Biomedicals).

I have heard lots of people use [NaOH extraction](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23121735) to get DNA from tissue and cell preps, but none of the first three worked for me after 2-3 tries.  One of the people in my lab said that I could replace the bead beater with vortexing with glass beads.

I tried vortexing with beads with all four methods, including the kit and only the kit worked.  I got a PCR result from control primers.

When you look at the costs of getting all the ingredients for the buffers kits are not so expensive - $1-$2 per sample.

A lot of these kits can handle solid animal tissues, though the one I have doesn't specifically cite hair.  I would try it out.

I guess the point of my post was that there are lots of simple sounding published methods, but they don't always produce results without a bunch of debugging.  I know [alkaline lysis](http://faculty.plattsburgh.edu/donald.slish/Extraction.html) has worked for several people I know and is the basis of the kits.  Its pretty simple.

That's my experience anyway.

Comment: Awesome to see you active (you are one of two with 20k+ and full privileges after graduation :-) ! However, I was wondering if the *buccal cavity* contains hair, given OPs question?

Comment: Great, interesting, +1!